# Simple Ajax form submit!? (Can't understand)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I will try to explain my code simple. Basicly I got 2 different files:

```
fun.php
class.fun.php
```

I want to post my forms with ajax, so it won't refresh page.
      In `class.fun.php` I have got `reportForm` for each post.

```
<!-- REPORT MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade report_post_<?php echo $post['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <b><center><div class="modal-header">Report Post</div></center></b>     
            <form class="horiziontal-form" id="reportForm" action="../Pages/fun.php?action=reportPostForm" method="post">                     
            <center><textarea name="report" style="width:80%; height:200px; margin-top:20px; resize:vertical;" placeholder="Please describe your Report!"></textarea></center>
            <input type="hidden" name="addedby" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $myRow['id']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="image_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" />
            <div class="modal-footer"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" /></div>                                  
            </div>               
            </div>
    </form> 
    </div>
    <!-- END OF REPORT MODAL -->
```

And after form I got ajax function:

```
     <script> 
   $("#reportForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: request_method,
        data : form_data
    }).done(function(response){ //
        $("#server-results").html(response);
    });
});
    </script>
```

When I click button `submit` I want to send form data to `fun.php`

This is how I receive data in `fun.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['reportPostForm'])){
    $image_id = strip_tags($_POST['image_id']);
    $report = strip_tags($_POST['report']);
    $addedby = strip_tags($_POST['addedby']);

    $fun->reportPost($image_id,$report,$addedby);       
}
```

And send them to other function in `class.fun.php`

But at this moment nothing happens. I have been looping trought many
tutorials and can't understand how to make this work. Im newbie in
javascript. I have got working upvote/downvotes scripts where I pass only `post_id` and it works.

I have got script for upvote that works:

```
$("#upvote_<?php echo $post['id'];?>").click(function(){
$.ajax(
  { url: "fun.php?upvote-btn=true?action=select&image_id=<?php echo $post['id'];?>", 
    type: "get",
    success: function(result){
        $('#upvote_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').load(document.URL +  ' #upvote_<?php echo $post['id'];?>');
        $('#downvote_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').load(document.URL +  ' #downvote_<?php echo $post['id'];?>');
        $('#comment_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').load(document.URL +  ' #comment_<?php echo $post['id'];?>');
        $('#share_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').load(document.URL +  ' #share_<?php echo $post['id'];?>');
        $('#report_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').load(document.URL +  ' #report_<?php echo $post['id'];?>');
        $('#report_btn_<?php echo $post['id'];?>').load(document.URL +  ' #report_btn_<?php echo $post['id'];?>');
        document.getElementById("result-box").innerHTML = result;
    }
  });
```

});

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end of your submit function as this will prevent the event from bubbling up. Not sure if that will fix the problem but a start :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't get any errors. Im running this on localhost - xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `fun.php` you are checking for `$_post['reportPostForm']` but this is not sent via post on this ajax call. your firm doesn't have this inputime and that's why nothing is happening. Try `if(isset($_POST['report'])`

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['report'])){
    $image_id = strip_tags($_POST['image_id']);
    $report = strip_tags($_POST['report']);
    $addedby = strip_tags($_POST['addedby']);

    $fun->reportPost($image_id,$report,$addedby); 
   echo "Done";

}
```

Also add the  `<div id='server-results'></div>` to your form so that you can show the resutls.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<b>
<center>
  <div class="modal-header">Report Post</div>
</center>
</b>
<form class="horiziontal-form" id="reportForm" action="../Pages/fun.php?action=reportPostForm" method="post">
  <center>
    <textarea name="report" style="width:80%; height:200px; margin-top:20px; resize:vertical;" placeholder="Please describe your Report!"></textarea>
  </center>
  <input type="hidden" name="addedby" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $myRow['id']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="image_id" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" />
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id='server-results'></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like upVote function seems to work because there is nothing that needs to happen in server side when this is called via Ajax. Can you post all the code on fun.php?

Comment: My Fun Code is 646lines big, really sure to want see it all?

Comment: I edited my answer. Check and if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what is not working. 
The file is correct.

Only problem is in fun.php as you do:

```
if(isset($_POST['reportPostForm'])){
$image_id = strip_tags($_POST['image_id']);
$report = strip_tags($_POST['report']);
$addedby = strip_tags($_POST['addedby']);

$fun->reportPost($image_id,$report,$addedby);
}
```

But you are sending $_POST['addedby'], $_POST['image_id'] and $_POST['report'].

The one you are checking $_POST['reportPostForm'] do not exists.

Try to do the if against one of the three values you are passing.